# Positioning multiple objects at once

Tags: interface, export, transforms

I am exporting some of my meshes, how can I position them to the center of the world all withouht having to set the position one by one ? I know I can select all of them and position them by eye-balling it with the grab mode, but how can I position them all at once by entering the coordinates in the ''transform menu'' ?

Because for now, when i enter the coordinates, it only takes into consideration the last mesh that was selected in the group.

Comment: Snap cursor to center, select all, snap selected to cursor. Use offset to not change their positions relative to each other.

Comment: Ohhh I forgot about the shift+s menu. Thank you ! :)

Comment: Also press `Alt` while entering [0,0,0] value in the coordinates properties box, so it applies to all selected objects, instead of active one only

Comment: Not while entering. Alt + click into the coordinate properties box = set all selected objects. After entering Alt + Enter = move all selected objects according to active object.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I have followed

Selecting a destination (using existing origin point of that object)

1. Select base object
2. Press **Shift + S** and choose `Cursor to Active`
3. Got to **FINAL STEPS**

If you want to move an object to another object vertex in Blender

1. Select base object (destination)
2. Select `Edit mode` and choose the destination vertex
3. Press **Shift + S** `Cursor to selected` go to `Object mode`
4. Got to **FINAL STEPS**

**FINAL STEPS**
Now regardeless of what steps you follow above here are the steps to move other objects to the chosen destination above

- Select the other object(s) (single or just shitf + click on each)
- Press **Shift + S** and choose `Selection to cursor (Keep offset)`

Feel free to improve it since I'm very new to Blender